# ER bridge in black hole merger

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, wormholes

Does an ER bridge between two black holes mean they are "entangled" and what happens to the ER bridge if a merger happened?

Comment: See comment below. I have more sources on this subject if you need them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Einstein-Rosen bridge is a property of the maximal extension of the Schwarzschild geometry. It doesn't exist for astrophysical black holes that form by gravitational collapse.

> I wondered in the case that these two black holes were already entangled

"Entangled" isn't the right word here. Entanglement is a quantum-mechanical thing.

If you want to know what happens when the two event horizons in an Einstein-Rosen bridge collide, then the answer is that they can't collide. One is a past event horizon and one is a future event horizon.

If you want to know what happens when the two mouths of a traversible wormhole collide, that would be a different question. To make it a meaningful question, you would have to describe what wormhole solution you have in mind.

Comment: He's asking about the EPR=ER conjecture. This is relatively recent work between Leonard Susskind and Juan Maldecena. Wookie, have you already read Cool Horizons for Entangled Black Holes from 2013, found here? https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0533 If this paper doesn't give you a starter, so you can derive what happens, comment back here and we'll try working it together.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, theoretically, an ER bridge between two black holes means they MIGHT be entangled. There is a conjecture called the EPR=ER Conjecture. The original paper, called Cool Horizons for Entangled Black Holes can be found here:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0533

by Leonard Susskind and Juan Maldecena from 2013.

However, I want to caution that this conjecture has not been empirically tested yet, though it is theoretically testable in quantum computer networks, as it has been suggested by Leonard Susskind and Ying Zhao here:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.04354

If the tests regarding the EPR=ER conjecture yield validating results, then yes, provisionally, two black holes, connected by an ER bridge, are in fact entangled.

As for what happens during a black hole merger between the two black holes to the entanglement or ER bridge, I don't know at this time. I would recommend reading the original paper listed, and try to derive the answer from the behavior of the black holes in the conjecture. I have my suspicions as to what might happen, but will not include them in this answer as they are only opinions at this time.

Comment: Thank you for the links to the papers. That will keep me occupied for a while. Ben Crowell makes the important point in his answer above that ER bridges don't exist for black holes that form by stellar collapse.

Comment: Fair enough. All the best in the meantime with your work.